# Create Windows-Service with compiled WCF-service

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, windows-services

I have a **compiled WCF-Service** (*.exe) with all needed dll's and now I need to create a **windows-Service** out of this without having the source. Is this possible? If so, how to achieve this? The wcf-service is a **console-based-service** and the console must **not be displayed** while the windows-service is running

allready tried with sc.exe, but that ends in following error when I start the windows-service:

> "The service MyService could not be started"
>
> Error 1053: The service does not respond on time on the start- or control-request

-> Error-message translated from German

Answer (score 1):

If the program implements the `ServiceBase` class you can use `installutil` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95.aspx) to install the service.

Otherwise you can have a look at `srvany` (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890)

You might run into issues if the service was planned as a console application, because you never know if at some point user input is required or a message box pops up. In this case your application will become unresponsive and it will be very hard to track down the cause.

Comment: `Installutil` I've tested, at the end he told me it was successfull, but either the service was listed, nor it was started (listening on port 8080). No the service doesnt need user-interaction or doesnt output messages on the console, it must run in the background. Is it possible to bind the WCF-service over `srvany` into the windows-services?